# Issues with images in latex

Tags: floats, positioning

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)

I want to to show three plots in a page such that the first two plots are on one line and the third plot on the second. However, I am having some issues with the plot in latex. In my case, I am having the first two images in a row. Then I get the paragraph that was supposed to come after the three plots and then at the end the last plot. I thought it was because of the size of the plot. So, I tried to reduce the size to see if it makes a difference. But even if the size of the plots is so small that it can easily accommodate in the space occupied by the paragraph, it's still pushed down and comes after the paragraph. How can I fix this?

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{a.jpg}
\caption{a}
\label{fig:a}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.5\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{b.jpg}
\caption{b}
\label{fig:b}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{c.jpg}
\caption{c}
\label{fig:c}
\centering
\end{figure}

\subsection{Details}
About the details...........
```

Now the issue is the I have the first two images side by side and then I was expecting the third images but instead of that I have the subsection Details and the third image follows it

Comment: You'll have to include some source code for anyone to be able to help.

Comment: Have you tried something like:
\includegraphics{1.jpg}
\includegraphics{2.jpg}\\includegraphics{3.jpg}

Comment: The issue is that the text after i.e Details in my case is coming before the images. I want the three images to appear first and then only the Details subsection

Comment: I fixed the issue. Use \begin{figure}[H]

Comment: I think that you will have better luck if you use
[`subfloat`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfloat) or [`subfig`](http://ctan.org/pkg/subfig).

Comment: `figure` is a so called *float* and will not be positioned exactly where the code is located. This is on purpose. LaTeX is written for professional results and you won't find a book which has a figure just in between texts on a page. They are always either on top or bottom of a page or on a page of their own. See the above linked questions for further help and information. The `[H]` setting provided by the `float` package you mentioned is one way to do it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Your question was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.